# ROS: Sensor data via USB

Tags: c++, ros

Im working on a project and i want to use a sensor. I can plug in the sensor via usb. I do not need any driver for the sensor. My task is to have an access to the sensor data. I have followed the tutorial on this page:
http://clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ros/Udev%20Rules.html
But i dont know if this is my soution. I dont know what to do now. How can i have access to the data in ROS? Do i have to create a publisher?

Comment: How can I take raw data from the sensors and publish it to a ROS topic?

Comment: You say that you do not need a driver for this sensor? Is it a serial-based sensor?

Comment: Yes it is a serial based sensor

Comment: Please give some information about the sensor. Maybe there are already ROS packages available.

Answer (score 1):

The use of udev rules is orthogonal to the publishing of sensor data. Look at the publisher side of the [Writing a Publisher and Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial, but instead of pushing string messages to the topic, push data from your sensor instead.

If there is not already a standard message type to encapsulate your data, you can [define a custom message type](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg).

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution. I had to do it like that:
https://github.com/garyservin/serial-example/blob/master/src/serial_example_node.cpp